# Using embedded documents in spring data aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB document like this example doc:

```
{
    "_id" : "A",
    "articleNumber" : "0123456",
    "shopDependentProperties" :
       { 
                    "shop" : "DE",
                    "foo" : "foo",
                    "bar" : "bar"
     }
}
```

and want to pull out the properties of shopDependentProperties, to have the following result

```
{
    "_id" : "A",
    "articleNumber" : "0123456",
    "foo" : "foo",
    "bar" : "bar"
}
```

In MongoDB Shell i can solve it this way:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project:
        {       
          _id : "$_id",   
          articleNumber : "$articleNumber",
          foo:"$shopDependentProperties.foo",
          bar:"$shopDependentProperties.bar"
        }
    }
 ]
)
```

But: In Spring Data MongoDB i can't extract the embedded document contents.
I tried many combinations, nothing worked. For example:

```
ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project("_id");
projection.andExpression("shopDependentProperties.foo").as("foo");
projection.andExpression("shopDependentProperties.bar").as("bar");
System.out.println(projection.toDBObject(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT));
```

will ignore the shopDependentProperties.shop stuff and just print out

```
{ "$project" : { "_id" : 1}}
```

Any suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to do it in MongoDB, the problem was about doing the same thing in Spring Data.

But it works the same way, why didn't I try that before?

**Solution:**

ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project(
        "brandName",
        "$shopDependentProperties.foo",
        "$shopDependentProperties.bar" );

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but as of

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

you specify included / excluded fields like this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
  {
    $project:
      {       
        _id : "$_id",
        articleNumber : 1,
        "shopDependentProperties.foo": 1,
        "shopDependentProperties.bar": 1
      }
  }
```

]
  )

Further down they explain, how to include embedded documents in the projection result.